# Angular material switch between mat-icon-button and mat-button

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Is there any prettier way to switch between mat-icon-button and mat-button, depending on media queries? I've made a demo of my current solution, but it needs two independent button.

```
<button type=button mat-icon-button fxHide fxShow.lt-sm (click)="onEdit($event)">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
<button type="button" mat-button fxHide.lt-sm (click)="onEdit($event)">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> Edit
</button>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-responsive-buttons)

Comment: It is possible to show only one button. Use `ObservableMedia` in your typescript code to set a flag that adds the appropriate button attribute based on the screen size.

Comment: Did you mean like [THIS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-btns-with-observablemedia)? This is not working.

Comment: ObservableMedia is a wrapper of an Observable, so it does nothing until you subscribe to it. Look this example it describes exactly what you need: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia#2-observablemediaasobservable

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, currently using this solution.

Component.html:

```
<button
        mat-button
        [ngClass]="isBigDevice() ? 'mat-stroked-button' : 'mat-icon-button'"
        color="accent"
        type="button"
        (click)="coolMethodToDoStuff()"
        [disabled]="isSelected() && contextTypeIsSomething()">
    <span *ngIf="isBigDevice()">Edit</span>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!isBigDevice()">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

There is a problem/annotation: You need to add the base button style/property `mat-button`. If you dont, you will get an error that `color` is no property for this kind of html-element. The advantages are, if you have multiple properties on one button or conditions for `disabled`, `hidden` or `*ngIf` you dont need them twice. I know with `*ngIf`the readability is lacking, but currently its the best way to avoid a huge junk of duplicate code.

Next step for me: I will build an directive for things like this.

Edit:

More over this is my MediaQueryService:

```
import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MediaQueryService implements OnDestroy {

private _breakpointArray = {
    isXSmall: false,
    isSmall: false,
    isMedium: false,
    isLarge: false,
    isXLarge: false,
};
private _destroy$ = new Subject();

constructor(
    private _breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
) {
    this._breakpointObserver
        .observe([
            Breakpoints.WebLandscape,
            Breakpoints.WebPortrait,
        ])
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this._destroy$)
        )
        .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
            _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.WebLandscape)
                ? this.webOrientationChangeLogger('landscape')
                : this.webOrientationChangeLogger('portrait');
        });

    this._breakpointObserver.observe([
            Breakpoints.XSmall,
            Breakpoints.Small,
            Breakpoints.Medium,
            Breakpoints.Large,
            Breakpoints.XLarge,
        ]
    )
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this._destroy$)
        )
        .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
            this._breakpointArray.isXSmall = _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.XSmall);
            this._breakpointArray.isSmall = _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Small);
            this._breakpointArray.isMedium = _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Medium);
            this._breakpointArray.isLarge = _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Large);
            this._breakpointArray.isXLarge = _breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.XLarge);
        });
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
}

public get isSmallDevice(): boolean {
    return this.getBreakpointBoolean('isXSmall') || this.getBreakpointBoolean('isSmall');
}

public get isBigDevice(): boolean {
    return this.getBreakpointBoolean('isXLarge') || this.getBreakpointBoolean('isLarge');
}

public getBreakpointBoolean(breakpointName: string): boolean {
    return this._breakpointArray[breakpointName];
}

private webOrientationChangeLogger(orientation: string) {
    console.log(orientation);
}
```

}

And inside the component where I am using the button I just call the `isBigDevice()` method and return the boolean.

Component.ts:

```
public isBigDevice(): boolean {
    return this._mediaQueryService.isBigDevice();
}
```

You could also try use this the `fxShow`, `fxHide` properties of angular material.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<button mat-button [ngClass]="condition ? 'mat-raised-button' : 'mat-icon-button'">Button</button>
```